# Java is using volatile keyword memory efficient?

Tags: java, memory, volatile, memory-efficient

If using 1 volatile variable, does it turn off cpu caching in for other related non volatile variables as well?

Comment: Why would a micro-optimization like this matter to anyone?  I thought it had to do with thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

no, it only prevents that variable from being loaded up to cpu cache and modified there. more precisely, it forces the cpu to flush its cache after accessing the volatile field. see [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile) for more complate details

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't "turn off" caching.  But yes it does *typically* cause a flush of other pending writes (when you write a `volatile`) or at least some cache invalidation (when you read a `volatile`) ... and both of these use extra memory bandwidth, and impact on performance.

Consider this example:

```
public volatile int foo;
public int bar;

/* thread 1 */

bar = 1; // A
foo = 1; // B

/* thread 2 */
System.err.println("foo = " + foo);  // C
System.err.println("bar = " + bar);  // D
```

The JLS says that A *happens-before* B and C *happens-before* D.  If C in thread 2 is *subsequent* to B in thread 1, then B *happens-before* C, and therefore A *happens-before* D.

If A *happens-before* D then the value written to `bar` at A must be available as `bar` at D ... assuming that nothing else wrote to `bar` in the meantime.

It is implementation specific *how* this is actually achieved.  But there are certainly affects on cached data ... including cached copies of non-volatile fields.

Assuming a typical memory architecture, and assuming that thread 1 and thread 2 don't share caches, this means that:

- both `foo` and `bar` must be flushed to main memory  by thread 1 at B, and
- at C any of thread 2's cached copies of `foo` and `bar` must be discarded.

My understanding is that this is typically implemented using cache invalidate and cache flush instructions.

---

The bottom line is that use of `volatile` can have significant performance impact on a multi-core system due to the extra memory traffic that it generates.

Answer (score 0):

The volatile keyword has nothing to do with memory. It is a concurrency issue.

**Edit**
The volatile keyword has nothing to do with memory efficiency. It is a concurrency issue.

Comment: actually it does have to do with memory. specifically with thread-local storage and cpu caching

Comment: TLS!! Where did you pick that TLS and volatile are related?

Comment: Maybe you and I just have different definitions for the word efficiency, but I will update my post.

Comment: writing to a volatile field will flush any modification from your cpu cache to main memory. this obviously has some performance impact.

Comment: s/some/negligible? Also as mentioned, that's not how I define memory efficiency. In my world view memory efficiency is about space, not about performance. For instance a HashMap is less memory efficient than a TreeMap, because it (on average) uses more memory to store the same amount of data. A Lookup Table is less memory efficient, because it uses more memory than doing the arithmetic in real time. It may be faster (thus more computational efficient).